# Citations in tabularx cause all bibliography entries to not have a number

Tags: biblatex, biber, tabularx

If I invoke `\cite` within a `tabularx` environment and `biblatex` is loaded with `defernumbers=true` and `sorting=none`, references do not get a number.

I get these warnings:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                file
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

But nothing changes no matter how many times I rerun `biber` and `pdflatex`.

If I change the `tabularx` environment to plain `tabular` references do get a number.

I have already brought this to PLK's (`biblatex` maintainer) attention [on the `biblatex` bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/239) and he has said that:

> This is because `sorting=none` invokes a special check to see if citation order has changed so that re-run messages can be issued for biber. For some reason, `tabularx` is triggering this every time. You can see something strange going on by just runing latex once and they you get, in the `.bcf`:
>
> ```
> <bcf:citekey order="1">gob</bcf:citekey>
> <bcf:citekey order="3">michael</bcf:citekey>
> <bcf:citekey order="4">tobias</bcf:citekey>
> ```
>
> There is a missing "2" order. With plain `tabular`, it is there. So `tabularx` is doing something strange like processing the `\cite` twice. I think it's worth asking this as a TSE question as the `tabularx` people are around on there.

## Issue:

[image: Issue]

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Article{gob,
  title           = {I've Made a Huge Mistake: The Hermano Story},
  author          = {Bluth, Gob},
  journal         = {Journal of Magicians},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{michael,
  title           = {Her?},
  author          = {Bluth, Michael},
  journal         = {Sudden Valley},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{tobias,
  title           = {Never-nudism},
  author          = {F{\"u}nke, Tobias},
  journal         = {Blue Man Group},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  defernumbers=true,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Check this out~\cite{gob}.

\section{A section}
% With plain tabular, it works with sorting=none or no sorting option.
% \begin{tabular}{ll}
  % \textbf{The term \enquote{issue} is used to refer to:} & \textbf{Reference(s)} \\ \hline
  % An issue. & \cite{michael}
% \end{tabular}

% With tabularx, it does not work with sorting=none.
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll}
  \textbf{The term \enquote{issue} is used to refer to:} & \textbf{Reference(s)} \\ \hline
  An issue. & \cite{michael}
\end{tabularx}

\nocite{tobias}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

**Extra information:** With the latest stable `biblatex` release, numbers are omitted altogether and only the brackets are shown. With the dev 3.0 version, all bibliography entries are assigned the number 0. But this is irrelevant because the same `.bcf` issue is seen in both cases:

> This numbering in the `.bcf` issue also occurs with the released 2.9 version of `biblatex`. Further runs throw an error with 2.9 due to issues already fixed in in 3.0 but this strange `tabularx` behaviour is there. — PLK

Comment: Just to be picky: what's the meaning of using `tabularx` with just `l` columns?

Comment: @egreg It was to avoid questions of the sort 'have you tried this without X-type columns?'. `:-)`

Comment: Well, the problem is quite certainly in the fact that `tabularx` squashes the table body a few times in order to measure the columns' widths. At least an `X` column is necessary for the example to be meaningful, or the answer would be “use `tabular`”.

Comment: @egreg Yes, of course. The actual tables I use are more complicated than that. So plain `tabular` is not really an option.

Comment: With biblatex 2.8a it works fine

Comment: Hmm, ok, I will need to look at relevant commits for 2.9.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks for letting me know. David's answer works, but let's see if PLK can resolve the issue from within `biblatex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do the cite on the final run (it means the cite text isn't used in the column widths calculation, but mostly it isn't too important. (a more careful definition could use the text without duplicating whatever information biblatex is using)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Article{gob,
  title           = {I've Made a Huge Mistake: The Hermano Story},
  author          = {Bluth, Gob},
  journal         = {Journal of Magicians},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{michael,
  title           = {Her?},
  author          = {Bluth, Michael},
  journal         = {Sudden Valley},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{tobias,
  title           = {Never-nudism},
  author          = {F{\"u}nke, Tobias},
  journal         = {Blue Man Group},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  defernumbers=true,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Check this out~\cite{gob}.

\section{A section}
% With plain tabular, it works with sorting=none or no sorting option.
% \begin{tabular}{ll}
  % \textbf{The term \enquote{issue} is used to refer to:} & \textbf{Reference(s)} \\ \hline
  % An issue. & \cite{michael}
% \end{tabular}

% With tabularx, it does not work with sorting=none.
\let\zz\hfuzz
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll}
  \textbf{The term \enquote{issue} is used to refer to:} & \textbf{Reference(s)} \\ \hline
  An issue. & \ifx\zz\hfuzz\cite{michael}\fi
\end{tabularx}

\nocite{tobias}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, David! I can confirm that this works, even under a fairly complicated setup that includes `refsegment`s, custom bibliography environments, and `tabularx` in `tcolorbox`es. I won't accept this just yet in case PLK can solve the issue from `biblatex`s side of things (which would be more convenient). Marco Daniel commented above that the issue does not exist with `biblatex` 2.8a so it may be a `biblatex` bug after all.

Comment: I think that this was a biblatex regression. I don't quite understand this strange interaction with tabularx but I think this is now fixed in the 3.0 dev version.

Comment: @PLK tabularx evaluates its body several times, it takes some precautions to stop for example labels being written multiple times, or latex counters being incremented multiple times, but depending on the coding style it can't catch everything. (AMS alignments are similar but always typeset twice, tabularx iterates towards a final width so can take several passes)

Comment: Ah, ok, that explains the non-contiguous cite order counter in the .bcf. This should not normally cause problems.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmm, I have fixed the main problem in biblatex with the bad numbering but the tabularx version still does something strange - I never find the citation in the aux file and so there are persistent re-run messages. I think perhaps we need to patch tabularx internals in biblatex to avoid multiple \cites?

Comment: @PLK is it multiple write to the aux file that causes problems or re-doing global defs (tx tries to prevent the former but it can't catch all idioms) if there is some reasonably generic thing I can do in tx I may be able to do that rather than you (and any other package) having to patch tx, let me know:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've put some details and a MWE here: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/242

Comment: I'll accept David's answer since it resolves the issue. I'll be keeping an eye on the bug-tracker in the meanwhile. Thank you David and @PLK for all your help!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - that fix seems to fix the internal numbering and .aux file issues - do you think there is some way to patch tabularx to always do this?

Comment: @PLK I'll have a look, the difficulty of patching \cite is not patching cite, but making it work with natbib and cite and hyperref and biblatex and....

Comment: Did the plan to do something about this in `tabularx` ever take off? This came up in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468475/35864 again and I think I have tracked this down to a global assignment that happens during one of the measurment runs and then blocks the typesetting run doing the real work. I'm a bit out of ideas how to resolve this. Is there a `tabularx` hook to disable certain commands during the measurement run?

Comment: I added the results of my investigation to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/242 if you are interested.

Comment: @moewe it's pretty scary trying to guess in tabularx how to patch every possible citation package (or how to patch any without breaking the rest) it might be better if I add a hook to tabularx to allow packages to add commands that are redefined during trial runs, and then leave it to biblatex to use whatever definitions it needs as it (or you:-) probably have a better idea than tabularx (or I:-) do...

Comment: Yes, I guess it shouldn't really be `tabularx`'s job to patch/redefine every posible command that might have issues with being executed several times, but typeset only once. A hook to disable certain commands for a trial run would be very convenient.

Comment: With the recently released `biblatex` 3.13 citations in `tabularx` should work even without this clever workaround.