# Bibliography with citations in tabularx and defernumbers=true only prints [0]

Tags: biblatex, citing, tabularx, biber

In my document, I need a lot of citations. However, my bibliography stopped working all of a sudden. All the citations in the document and the bibliography are [0] (instead of the excpected [1], [2], etc).

I seem to have figured out that this happens if I have more than exactly 100 citekeys (please don't judge me for my excessive citing).

Another problem seems to be the **defernumbers=true**, as when I set it to **defernumbers=false**, the citations and bibliography work just fine, even with 101+ citekeys.

I import the biblatex-package as follows:

```
\usepackage[hyperref=true, style=numeric, citestyle=numeric, sorting=none, defernumbers=true, backend=biber, backref=false]{biblatex}
```

An MWE doesn't make much sense here, since everything works just fine until I reach the 101st citekey.

My questions are:

1. Am  I right in the assumption that the 101+ citekeys can be an issue?
2. Is there a workaround? I split my bibliography into different topics, so I'd like to use defernumbers=true. If I have no other choice, I will have to do without, though.

Thank you! =)

**UPDATE:**
Apparently, the 100 citations were a coincidence. The issue seems to be with citations in a tabularx. Removing the citations within the table or setting defernumbers=false resolves the problem. I updated this question's title, too.

*main.tex*

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx}

%---Bibliography---%
\usepackage[hyperref=true, style=numeric, citestyle=numeric, sorting=none, 
defernumbers=true, backend=biber, backref=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliographyTable.bib}

\defbibfilter{bib:filter:literatur}{( type=book or type=incollection or type=inproceedings or type=article or type=thesis )}
\defbibfilter{bib:filter:report}{( type=report or type=techreport )}

\begin{document}

\input{mweTable.tex}

\newpage
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliography}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, filter=bib:filter:literatur, title={Literature}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=online, title={Online}] 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, filter=bib:filter:report, title={Reports}] 

\end{document}
```

*mweTable.tex*

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{ | X | X | X | }
        \hline
        \textbf{A} 
        \cite{bib:1}\cite{bib:2}    

        & \textbf{B}
        \cite{bib:3}\cite{bib:4}\cite{bib:5}    

        & \textbf{C}
        \cite{bib:6}\cite{bib:7}

        \tabularnewline 
        \hline

        a 
        \cite{bib:1}\cite{bib:2} 

        & b 
        \cite{bib:9} 

        & c 
        \cite{bib:8}

        \tabularnewline \hline

    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

 \cite{bib:10} 
 \cite{bib:11}
 \cite{bib:12}
 \cite{bib:13}
 \cite{bib:14}
 \cite{bib:15}
```

*bibliographyTable.bib*

```
@Report{bib:1,
    author      =   {Author 1},
    title       =   {Title 1},
    institution =   {Institution 1},
    year        =   {2016},
    month       =   {9},
    day         =   {19},
    url         =   {https://www.mwe.com},
    urldate     =   {2018-12-18}
}

@article{bib:2,
    author = {Author 2},
    year = {2010},
    month = {05},
    pages = {},
    title = {Title 2},
    volume = {10},
    journal = {Journal 2},
    doi = {10.21334}
}

@incollection{bib:3,
author  = {Author 3},
title       = {Title 3},
booktitle   = {Booktitle 3},
publisher   = {Publisher 3},
address     = {Address 3},
year        = {2018},
editor      = {Editor 4},
chapter     = {1},
doi         = {10.577889},
url         = {www.mwe.com}
}


@online{bib:4,
    title           = {Title},
    author          = {Author},     
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-12-29}
}

@online{bib:5,
    title           = {Title},
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com},
    urldate         = {2018-12-29}
}

@online{bib:6,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-12-29}
}

@online{bib:7,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-10-29}
}

@online{bib:8,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-10-29}
}

@online{bib:9,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-10-29}
}

@online{bib:10,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-12-29}
}

@online{bib:11,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-10-29}
}

@online{bib:12,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-10-29}
}

@online{bib:13,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-10-29}
}

@online{bib:14,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-10-29}
}

@online{bib:15,
    title           = {Title}, 
    author          = {Author}, 
    url             = {www.mwe.com}, 
    urldate         = {2018-10-29}
}
```

Comment: An complete example is needed to test the issue - even if the example needs 100 citekeys.

Comment: I just managed to successfully compile an example file with 191 references and `defernumbers=true` with and without a split bibliography (all number showed up as expected, there was no "[0]"). This demonstrates to me that in general `biblatex` can easily deal with more than 100 citations. Please delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf` ...) and try again. You may also want to check whether the issue is really that you cite 100 references or rather that you cite the 100th reference: Maybe one entry contains an error.

Comment: You can find my test file at https://gist.github.com/moewew/43d11f3cdb3cb9e29078f92a58346365

Comment: Thank you! I am working on an MWE but so far, I haven't even been able to reproduce the problem. It only occurs in my thesis document with more than 100 citekeys. I tried deleting the temp files but that didn't solve the problem. I'll keep working to find out what's wrong.

Comment: I think I found out it has to do with tabularx. The 100 citations must have been a conicidence, can't explain otherwise. Might be related to [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184206/citations-in-tabularx-cause-all-bibliography-entries-to-not-have-a-number)

Comment: Thank you for the example. I can reproduce the issue and will hopefully be able to have a closer look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the example. This is quite likely related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184206/35864, which you linked already. The workaround suggested there works here too. I'm not sure how much could be done on the `biblatex` side to smooth things over, but I will hopefully be able to dig into that tomorrow. For the time being allow me to comment that `\cite{a}\cite{b}` is bad style and that `\cite{a,b}` would be nicer (but this could just be for the MWE).

Comment: I think I could track down the issue in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/242, but I'm not sure what to do about it. I pinged David, maybe he has an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `biblatex` 3.13 has been updated to be more robust in situations like this.
>   With `biblatex` 3.13 or above citations will work as expected in `tabularx`.
>
> If at all possible, please update your TeX system.
>
> Some background info is at
>   https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/242
>
> The answer below is kept for historical interest.
>   The fix described here should *not* be applied for `biblatex` 3.13 or above.

This is indeed a similar issue to [Citations in tabularx cause all bibliography entries to not have a number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184206/35864) and David's workaround works here, too.

`tabularx` needs to measure the table contents to find the correct cell widths, during these meausurement runs TeX executes the code in the cells, but does not print the result. After the measurement run the result is typeset with the calculated lengths.

`tabularx` takes some measures to avoid unwanted side-effects from running the code several times before the actual typesetting step (all global assignments are potentially problematic, especially things like advancing counters). In particular `tabularx` blocks `\write` for the measurement runs.

`biblatex`'s cite commands write some auxiliary data to the `.aux` file on the first citation of an entry. If the first citation of an entry is in a `tabularx` context, an interplay between global assignments (`biblatex` keeps a global list of all cited entries: `\blx@cites`) and `\write` (on the first citation of an entry as indicated by the fact that the entry is not yet in `\blx@cites`, `biblatex` writes some citation info to the `.aux` file) means that the measurement run performs the global assignment but does not execute the `\write`. The subsequent typesetting run will not perform the `\write` again because according to the data in `\blx@cites` it should have happened already.

The issue is tracked at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/242. The workaround that is currently on the table (and that may make it into a future version of `biblatex`) delays writing the info to the `.aux` file to the end of the document. That means that the interplay between the global assignment and `\write` in `tabularx` cells is avoided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, defernumbers=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@citation@entry#1#2{%
  \blx@bibreq{#1}%
  \ifinlist{#1}\blx@cites
    {}
    {\listgadd{\blx@cites}{#1}}%
  \ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}
    {}
    {\listcsgadd{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}{#1}}%
  \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@segm{\the\c@refsection}{\the\c@refsegment}{\detokenize{#1}}}%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
       {\ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
          {}
          {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}
       {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \begingroup
  \def\do#1{\blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@cite{#1}}}%
  \dolistloop\blx@cites
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{geer}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    \cite{sigfridsson} \cite{geer,nussbaum}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\cite{worman,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The citations show as [1] in the text before the table, [2] [1, 3] in the table and [4, 3] after the table.]