# "Undefined references" but working bibliography with biblatex style ieee and tabu

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, tabu, ieee-style

I'm using the `ieee` style of biblatex for publications, as well as `tabu` for tables. I found some strange error within the interaction of this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{sources.bib}
@inproceedings{testref,
    author={Testauthor},
    title={Testtitle},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[style = ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabu}{c}
        \cite{testref}
    \end{tabu}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces a table with the correct reference (after, of course, running latex and biber and latex again) as well as a correct bibliography, but the message about undefined references will remain, regardless of how often I run biber and latex. Removing `style = ieee` or changing `tabu` to `tabular` fixes this issue. Is this a bug or am I just doing something wrong? Whats going on? I would like to use both of them together, is there a fix for this?

UPDATE: It seems as this problem also exists with `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{sources.bib}
@inproceedings{testref,
    author={Testauthor},
    title={Testtitle},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[style = ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c}
        \cite{testref}
    \end{tabularx}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This MWE is the same as before, only the table preamble is updated to `tabularx` (and of course the package is added).

Comment: tabu is broken and unmaintained. You are basically on your own if you insist to use it. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/

Comment: Huh. I did not know that. Well, I'm not dead set to using `tabu`, I think I only need features also available in `tabularx`. Thanks for pointing that out. You can formulate an answer, I will be happy to mark that as accepted.

Comment: Although I just noticed that `tabularx` has the same problem... (or `style = ieee`, but I can't really do anything about that).
What is the best solution to producing `tabularx`-like tables with this style? `tabular*`?

Comment: I can not reproduce the behaviour you describe with a current `biblatex`. I seem to remember that I fixed an issue with `tabularx` in `biblatex` a while ago (*edit* see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/242 & https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/878, the fix was released in `biblatex` 3.13 from 2019-08-17). Can you make an update and try again?

Comment: I've added an example, I will check my version and do an update.

Comment: Ok, I'm using biblatex v3.10. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: If you don't want to update, you can try the workaround in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468475/35864 (I can't test if the workaround works at the moment).

Comment: Thanks, thats very helpful!

Comment: Any news here? Did you update your system or did you try the linked workaround?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to follow up. I'm currently using the workaround, which is fine. This is on my work laptop, which is running ubuntu. Since I'm more of a arch linux guy, I didn't have to right combination of motivation and time to look into updating my tex system, so there's that. It will come in time :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since the workaround works for you and the problem is not reproducible with a current version I think we can safely conclude that the problem is the same as in the linked question. So I closed the question as a duplicate.