# "There were undefined references. Please (re)run Biber" when reference is in a table despite all references are considered

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, tabularx, biber

My output looks fine. However there are the following warnings when compiling a document with references inside a table, when using TexLive. With MikTex this warnings will not occure:

> There were undefined references.
>
> Please (re)run Biber on the file: minimalexample and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85,tabularx}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber,sorting=none,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c}
            \cite{reference} \\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The appropriate bib-file is:

```
@article{reference,
  title={Reference Title},
  author={Name, S.},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
```

Is there a mistake in my code or could it be a bug?

**Edit:**
The Biber log file is:

> [0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.12
>
> [0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'minimalexample.blg'
>
> [24] biber:315> INFO - === Fr Feb  5, 2021, 23:31:16
>
> [46] Biber.pm:371> INFO - Reading 'minimalexample.bcf'
>
> [106] Biber.pm:889> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
>
> [119] Biber.pm:4093> INFO - Processing section 0
>
> [131] Biber.pm:4254> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'biblatex-examples.bib' for section 0
>
> [139] bibtex.pm:1512> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
>
> [362] bibtex.pm:1329> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'biblatex-examples.bib'
>
> [386] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
>
> [387] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
>
> [387] Biber.pm:3921> INFO - Sorting list 'none/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'none' and locale 'en-US'
>
> [387] Biber.pm:3927> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
>
> [389] bbl.pm:636> INFO - Writing 'minimalexample.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
>
> [390] bbl.pm:739> INFO - Output to minimalexample.bbl

Comment: I get no warning in a current texlive (I used biblatex-examples.bib and \cite{doody} for the test). But why on earth are you using the standalone class here?

Comment: With biblatex-examples.bib and \cite{doody} the problem remains. My texlive version is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 or LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian). I'm sorry for using standalone. I thought, it is the best option for a minimal example. However, I'm fairly inexperienced.

Comment: oh, sorry I have a current texlive 2020.

Comment: standalone is a very special class which forces a very non standard processing which can easily introduce issues specific to that class, so article is usually a better class  for general examples. However if the bibliography is not being built you should have an error from biber, can you show the biber log you get for the above document

Comment: Since I cannot reproduce the issue with an up-to-date system and the problematic system seems to be running `biblatex` 3.12, I think this is basically the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468475/35864 (minus the `defernumbers=true,` which just makes the issue more apparent). You could try the workaround suggested there, but maybe it is time to get a vanilla TeX live with the current updates (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864).

Comment: Yes, this is the same underlying issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468475/35864 (just that it is less visible because you don't have `defernumbers=true,`): I checked that I could reproduce the behaviour with `biblatex` 3.12 and that the workaround suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468475/35864 or an update to `biblatex` 3.13 resolve the issue.

Comment: @moewe You're right and also Davids workaround works for me. May be you answer my question with that information. So I can "accept" your solution.

Comment: Would you also be OK with closing the question as a duplicate? The answer would basically be the same.

Comment: Of course it is OK for me. As far as I can see, it's not my job to vote for closing. So you're welcome to do it.